# Rewrite customer API not working

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, soap-api-v2

I can't get this small extension for rewriting `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api` to work.

My files:
`/app/etc/modules/EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`/app/code/local/EnaDva/CustomerInfoApi/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <enadva_customerinfoapi>
                <class>EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi_Model</class>
            </enadva_customerinfoapi>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_api>EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi_Model_Customer_Api</customer_api>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

`/app/code/local/EnaDva/CustomerInfoApi/Model/Customer/Api.php`

```
<?php

class EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi_Model_Customer_Api extends Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api
{

    /**
     * Retrieve customer data
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return array
     */
    public function info($customerId, $attributes = null)
    {
        Mage::log('Hello from extended API call', null, true, 'success.log')

    }

}
```

Any suggestions to make this work?

EDIT:
I think I'm missing api.xml file in my extension etc folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your `/app/code/local/EnaDva/CustomerInfoApi/Model/Customer/Api.php` :

```
class EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi_Model_Customer_Customer_Api
```

Should be:

```
class EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi_Model_Customer_Api
```

Same problem in your `/app/code/local/EnaDva/CustomerInfoApi/etc/config.xml`:

```
EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi_Model_Customer_Customer_Api
```

Should be:

```
EnaDva_CustomerInfoApi_Model_Customer_Api
```

Or the other way around, move:

```
/app/code/local/EnaDva/CustomerInfoApi/Model/Customer/Api.php
```

To:

```
/app/code/local/EnaDva/CustomerInfoApi/Model/Customer/Customer/Api.php
```

Comment: Still not working. Really don't know what could be the problem.

Comment: @Iztok how are you testing it ? Did you flush the cache ?

Comment: Yes, cache flushed. Tried in two different magento installations and it is not working. If I change code in file /Mage/Customer/Model/Customer/Api.php the changes are reflecting in api call response.

Comment: @Iztok Ok try adding `<depends><Mage_Api /></depends>` to your `app/etc/modules` file after `<codePool>local</codePool>` . Also change your module version to `0.1.0`

Comment: Still nothing. I have tried <depends> also by myself before I have opened this question. It is possible that you try this on your shop? I'm calling this method with: $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); $sessionId = $proxy->login('username', 'password');
$result = $proxy->customerCustomerInfo($sessionId, '1');
var_dump($result);

Comment: @Iztok Can't see what you posted after with

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38086/discussion-between-iztok-and-raphael-at-digital-pianism).